# MYSQLI SELECT * FROM users WHERE steamid = $steamid Does not work

Tags: php, mysqli, steam

```
THE SQL WHERE funtion does not work!
```

I tryed everything but this code does not work,
please help me.

I want to rebuild steamcompanion.com.

```html
<?php
include 'SteamAuth/SteamConfig.php';
echo 'db.php connected;
$fruit1 = "localhost";
$fruit2 = "";
$fruit3 = "";
$fruit4 = "";

$conn = new mysqli($fruit1, $fruit2, $fruit3, $fruit4);

$steamid = $steamprofile['steamid'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE steamid = '$steamid'"; //DOES NOT WORK //$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE steamid = $steamid"; does not work too!

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=http://mynameisflare.rf.gd/">YOU ARE LOGGEDIN!!';
 exit;
} else {
$profileurl = $steamprofile['profileurl'];
$avatarmed = $steamprofile['avatarmedium'];
$avatarfull = $steamprofile['avatarfull'];
$peronaname = $steamprofile['personaname'];
$realname = $steamprofile['realname'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (id, name, email, profileurl, avatarmedium, avatarfull, steamid, realname, makes, wins)
VALUES ('', '$peronaname', 'PLEASE PROVIDE A EMAIL!', '$profileurl', '$avatarmed', '$avatarfull', '$steamid', '$realname', '0', '0')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=http://mynameisflare.rf.gd/">REDIRECTING YOU!';
 exit;
}
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

THE SQL WHERE funtion does not work!

Result of echo $sql, SELECT * FROM users WHERE steamid = 76561198173691810

Comment: `echo $sql;` what does that  show? where is `$steamprofile` defined?

Comment: `$steamprofile` needs to be contained in a single quote - `'$steamprofile'`

Comment: we have no idea where `$steamprofile` is coming from, nor if what you posted is full/actual code, since syntax highlighting is throwing something about an error in `echo 'db.php connected;`. So in a nutshell; check for errors, you're not doing that.

Comment: "Does not work" isn't a problem statement.

Answer (score -1):

At first check your connection. More details http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php

```
/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
```

If steamid is number column, you need not use single quote for this number.

Now check your $steamid with `echo $sql` whether you are getting number or not.

For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object, not boolean. But you are checking with `===` which means return value is boolean which is incorrect.

Hope these way you can troubleshoot.